# Appium Inspector find element with the path but appium for java doesn't

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium, mobile-automation

I'm testing a mobile app using appium + selenium + java

I have an element that I'm trying to find (in order to click on later) by using an xpath.

Here is the xpath: `//android.widget.TextView[@text='Mon email']`

When I use the Appium inspector in order to find the element, it works (and I can "tap" on it using said Appium inspector).

[image: XPath used in the Appium inspector]

However, when I try to find the same element using my java program, I get a "No such element" error even though the app open as it should (and in far less than 10 seconds):

```java
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //android.widget.TextView[@text='Mon email'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at ECM.MyStepdefs.iClickOnTextFromClass(MyStepdefs.java:92)
    at ✽.I click on text "Mon email" from class "android.widget.TextView"(file:/C:/Users/Blop/src/test/resources/ECM/login.feature:5)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'BLOP', ip: '194.170.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {appActivity: com.something.something.MainA..., appPackage: com.something.something, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appActivity: com.something.something.MainA..., appPackage: com.something.something, deviceName: My Phone, platformName: android}, deviceManufacturer: samsung, deviceModel: SM-J600FN, deviceName: 785112random74852, deviceScreenSize: 720x1480, deviceUDID: 84337random41285, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 9, takesScreenshot: true, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 18e2ca78-1253-1234-1234-12354564865215
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//android.widget.TextView[@text='Mon email']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:61)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:151)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:57)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    at ECM.MyStepdefs.iClickOnTextFromClass(MyStepdefs.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:57)
    at cucumber.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:65)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:43)
    at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:46)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:49)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$1.run(Runtime.java:82)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:217)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:79)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```java
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;

    @Before
    public void setDriver() {
        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.something.something");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.something.something.MainActivity");

        //Instantiate Appium Driver
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @When("I click on text {string} from class {string}")
    public void iClickOnTextFromClass(String text, String myClass) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//"+myClass+"[@text='"+text+"']")));
        MobileElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//"+myClass+"[@text='"+text+"']"));

        element.click();
    }

[...]

        iClickOnTextFromClass("Mon email", "android.widget.TextView");
```

For what it's worth, my code is perfectly working when I'm using it on "Google Play" :

```java
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.vending");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");

[...]

        iClickOnTextFromClass("Meilleurs classements", "android.widget.TextView");
```

I tried to change my xpath to `//*[contains(@text, 'email')]` but it didn't solve the issue (still not working on my app using java, but working on "google play" using java and working on my app using "Appium Inspector").

---

So, **any idea on how I can solve this so I'm finally able to find my element using java (for automated tests)?**

---

In case it matters, here is (the relevant part of) my pom:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why, but I updated my version of Appium to the [v1.15.1](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.15.1) and now things are working. I guess there was some incompatibility of versions somewhere.

Anyway, things are working now, which is great!